# jQuery .remove() not removing img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am putting together a monopoly game to teach myself JS, jQuery, etc...

As I am putting together the move token function, I can not figure out why the player token is not being removed at the prepend call.

Included here is a picture to show the result of the current code:

[prepend and remove not removing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUwIq.png)

```
function moveToken(player,PosToMove){
    $("#"+PosToMove).prepend($("#player"+player).remove());
    positionTokens(PosToMove);

}
```

Obviously variable "player" is the player who's turn it is, and "PosToMove" is the position to move to. This function gets called for the total amount on the dice roll, one call at a time, positionTokens simply arranges tokens if more than one token is on a property, it only effects the positioning of the tokens, so it does not pertain to this issue.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Word!

**EDIT**

Ok, so the prepend does remove as well, but now its somthing with my dice roll and call to move the token function.... I have been trying to get at it for a day now, anyone care to take a gander?

```
function rollDice() {
    try{
    var playerMarch = 0; 
    var die1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    var die2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    var rollTotal = die1+die2;
        if( currentTurn === 1){
            for(var i = 1; i <= rollTotal; i++){
                playerMarch++;
                moveToken(currentTurn,playerMarch);
                playerOne.currentPos++;
            }

        }
    return (die1 + die2);
    }
    catch(e){
        alert(e.name+" Message: "+e.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does remove return the element?

Comment: maybe look at .detach()

Comment: Consider native JavaScript for a simple task like this: `var target = document.getElementById(PosToMove); target.insertBefore(document.getElementById('player'+player), target.firstChild);`

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol Well..... that seemed to work, but where in the code that you provided, does it remove the element?

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol Actually, that may have been premature.... its throwing an error, tell me that the target.insertBefore is null even tho I know it is named to a correct property ID....

Comment: Just tried your original code in a JSFiddle and it seems to work for me. What I would do is console.log() the values of $("#"+PosToMove) and $("#player"+player) and make sure they point to the right elements.

Comment: @RomanElizen Using `.appendChild` (or `.insertBefore`) will *move* the element, so you don't need to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using prepend with a single jQuery object as parameter already move the element. Try this...

```
function moveToken(player,PosToMove){
    $("#"+PosToMove).prepend($("#player"+player));
    positionTokens(PosToMove);
}
```

Comment: He is correct prepend(), append(), etc. when the argument is an existing element in the DOM, will remove it from the DOM before prepending it.

Comment: @A. Iglesias Great, thank you! 

Now just have to figure out why my dice roll code is not working.